# How to make Notepad++ run script based on its name?

Tags: cmd, notepad++

I want to make notepad++ run the "ruby {filename_here}" command if the current filename  ends with .rb and "perl {filename_here}" if it ends with .pl. I've tried to use the NppExec plugin, but it can't do conditional stuff, so I wrote a bat

```
@echo off

if /i %~sx1 == .pl perl "%~f1"
if /i %~sx1 == .rb ruby "%~f1"
if /i %~sx1 == .php php "%~f1"
```

Now I can use it from the command line like C:\Program Files\Notepad++>runscript "D\pl.pl" and it works fine. Now how can I bind some key in Notepad++ to "runscript $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"? I've tried to use the Run->Run menu (F5), but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to put the file name at the end of the command.
In the Run(F5) dialog, try this:

```
runscript $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

If you want to test it out, you could put a `& pause` at the end, just to see if it worked.

You could also tweak your script a bit so that every file doesn't test for each extension, by using the dreaded `GOTO` command with file extension labels:

```
@echo off
GOTO %~sx1
:.pl
  perl "%~f1"
  GOTO end
:.rb
  ruby "%~f1"
  GOTO end
:.php
  php "%~f1"
  GOTO end
:end
```

Comment: In the current Notepad++ version `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` already contains file name.

Comment: There is one error here you need to make sure you use runscript "$(Full_CURRENT_PATH)" or else you will get an error if you script is in a folder that has spaces in it.

Comment: No need for the runscript.bat at all - just do "$(Full_CURRENT_PATH)" and Windows should send the file to the correct executable as long as file associations and PATHEXT are set correctly

Answer (score 5):

I had issues making it work so that it keeps the shell window opened while I take a look at what it did. <strike>Putting the "& pause" at the end didn't seem to help, until I added `cmd /c` at the beginning:</strike>

<strike>`cmd /c c:\php\php.exe -l "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"  & pause`</strike>

For keeping the command results on the screen, you can use /k switch, as suggested by George:
`cmd /k c:\php\php.exe -l "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

That works great, I use it for quick syntax checking in Notepad++.

Comment: You could also try using /k instead of /c and then get rid of the & pause. /c terminates where /k remains.

Comment: That's a good one, George. Looks like a man can never learn enough his shell switches :)

Answer (score 5):

In the notepad++ version 6.2, running on Windows, just use **"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"**, with the quotes, so the file will be opened using the default program associated to the file. So, be sure that "edit with notepad++" is **NOT** the default double click action.

Answer (score 1):

You could try npp_exec using the following script:

```
NPP_SAVE
SET Executer = execute$(EXT_PART)
NPP_EXEC "$(Executer)"
```

And then use a script named execute.rb:

```
perl $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) //or something like that
```

this method is described [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Source_Code)

Answer (score 1):

There is plugin called [RunMe](https://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins) that can open current file in default program. It is better solution than "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" command because it change current directory to the file path and that command run the file in N++ path.

Comment: I cleared the shortcut command for `mainmenu > Run` and set `Shell Execute current file` to `F5` but it doesn't take.  Strange.  If I call the function from the menu it works.