# Notepad++ question

Tags: notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Notepad++ run script based on its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106040/how-to-make-notepad-run-script-based-on-its-name)

I want to run an application through notepad++ by clicking Run>Run... But is there a way to get my current opened files path and put it in the Run dialog box automatically? I want to run a compiler and it needs to know the full path of my current file. It would be great to just press one key and the compiler would compile my file.

Answer (score 14):

Notepad++ has environment variables that you can access in your run script:

```
FULL_CURRENT_PATH   : E:\my Web\main\welcome.html
CURRENT_DIRECTORY   : E:\my Web\main\
FILE_NAME           : welcome.html
NAME_PART           : welcome
EXT_PART            : html
```

You access these by using `$(varname)`.

Comment: possibly helpful note: when you want to execute a `.bat` script in Windows you can use the following command in the `Run` -  `Run...` dialogue: `cmd /c "cd /D "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & "$(FILE_NAME)""` -  click `Save...` to save this command and assign a keyboard-short cut. 
The command will change to the directory of the current file (even when it's on another drive - thanks to `/D`) and then execute it. The double quotes make sure that also files and dirs with space characters work.

Answer (score 4):

To run a new command:

Select Run->Run.... A dialog will pop up asking for the path to the program and possible any command line parameters. You can use the browse button to search for your program. The drop down list provides recently run programs. The command line arguments can also be based on the status of the current document, and are always enclosed in $(...), where … can be:

`FULL_CURRENT_PATH`
the fully qualified path to the current document.

`CURRENT_DIRECTORY`
 The directory the current document resides in.

`FILE_NAME`
 The filename of the document, without the directory.

`NAME_PART`
 The filename without the extension.

`EXT_PART`
 The extension of the current document.

`NPP_DIRECTORY`
 The directory that contains the notepad++.exe executable that is currently running.

`CURRENT_WORD`
 The currently selected text in the document.

`CURRENT_LINE`
 The current line number that is selected in the document (0 based index, the first line is 0).

`CURRENT_COLUMN`
 The current column the cursor resides in (0 based index, the first position on the line is 0).

http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/commands