# How can I integrate PHP/Python Interpreter to Notepad++

Tags: php, python, editor, notepad++

I want If I am editing a php file I should be able to press a key combination or click a menu item that'll launch the php-cli and run my current file? How do I do it in Notepad++.

Also I need this for Python.

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend getting an actual IDE such as Eclipse which can launch files properly for you in a better environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1106040/272388

Comment: Well, I have Eclipse and Netbeans setup with debugging environment. I need this when i have to run something very quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly don't recommend installing an IDE for Python unless you use it for large-scale projects or work on large, complex scripts on a daily basis. Notepad++ works great with the **NppExec** plugin. I use the following steps:

1. Download (if it does not already exist) the NppExec plugin and place the `.dll` file in [Notepad++ installation path]\plugins
2. Open a Python file in Notepad++, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to execute
3. Type the following lines in the window that pops up:

   ```
   NPP_SAVE
   python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```
4. The above lines basically tell NppExec to "save the current Python file and run it using the **version of python that first appears in the path environment variables**"
5. Click on "Save" and type in a recognizable name such as 'run_python'
6. Go to the menubar, Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options..
7. Under 'Menu item', choose the script we just created above, and 'Add/Modify' it to the Menu items with a suitable name. This allows us to assign shortcut keys through Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin commands
8. Navigate to the script name and choose any shortcut keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
9. Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to save and run the Python file

A few points to note when using NppExec:

- Make sure that you check the option Plugins -> NppExec -> Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY). This makes sure that Python looks for the script in the **current** path, not the Notepad++ path.
- The console window that docks to the main editor window does not have word wrap turned on by default. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> within the console to activate word wrap and not miss any useful output data
- Kill a running Python script by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> within the console window

Once all this is done, Notepad++ basically functions like an IDE. It may lack features like `pdb` debugging, but it works really well with Python. I'm pretty sure the execution steps for Perl/PHP scripts are also more or less similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the "Run" menu option. It allows you to bind key combinations to applications.