# Notepad++ using "Run" command in a macro

Tags: macros, notepad++

Is it possible to create a macro in Notepad++ that is able to utilize the "Run" command so that I may call an external .exe to operate on the file specified? I am able to do it manually, but when I create a macro that includes the run (F5) and give it a specified command it fails to execute. Is this because the run command isn't supported when creating macros? If so, is there a work-around method?

Thanks

edit: to add context -- I've written a couple ruby scripts to facilitate data-entry that's done using notepad++, and would like to integrate them to the editor. Having them run by a shortcut method created by recording a macro seems to be the best way to do this, unless it's not possible to utilize the run command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the NppExec plugin (available in the [Notepad++ wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#N) ). It allows you to create mini-scripts with keywords that perform commands.

You will also be able to add your script in the contextual (right-click) menu, or assign a shortcut to it.

I personaly uses it to saves a sql file, place myself in the current directory, and then executes isql.exe (external executable) on that file. That simple script transforms my Notepad++ into a rather handy SQL IDE.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) and [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) editors can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you do it using only Notepad++.

Please see this thread:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/4805532

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using an external macro-manager, if possible. I'd like to have everything native to notepad++, so I can simply copy over the shortcuts.xml file to all of the computers that I need to have this macro on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have it all set up but are having issues with running it through Notepad++'s run command?
If so, try what I mentioned **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8007057/261332)**.

I had similar issues with running php compiler and resolved it with the "cmd /c" added like in that mentioned example. And a "& pause" at the end, just so I see what goes on.